# Sort vector of cv::Point2i clockwise

Tags: c++, sorting, opencv

I'm new and I have a `std::vector` of `cv::Point2i`:

```
vector<Point2i> x_y;
```

And I want to sort them clockwise!
How can I do it?

Comment: Clockwise relative to what?

Comment: @DanMašekFor example one point of this vector.

Comment: [edit] your question, so that it includes this information.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).
Overload (3) accepts a **custom comparator**, that should:

> returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered
> before) the second.

Your comparator should compare the angles of the lines connecting the points to the origin (or to any other rotation pivot).

Here is a complete example (replace `Point` with `cv::Point2i`):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> points = { {0,1}, {-1,0}, {-1,1}, {1,0} };

    Point pivot{ 0,0 }; // Select a point from the vector, or any other (will be used as rotation center).
    std::sort(points.begin(),
              points.end(),
              [pivot](Point const& p1, Point const& p2)
                     { return std::atan2(p1.y - pivot.y, p1.x - pivot.x) > std::atan2(p2.y - pivot.y, p2.x - pivot.x); });

    for (auto const& p : points)
    {
        std::cout << "{" << p.x << "," << p.y << "}" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that I used `>` in the comparator to get a clockwise order (in which large angles should come before small ones). Use `<` for an anti-clockwise order).

Output:

```
{-1,0}
{-1,1}
{0,1}
{1,0}
```